# MDB CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT mode with max-messages-in-transaction >1

Tags: jms

I have a need where I want to group messages received from a system based on certain criterion. For performance reasons, I  want to avoid persisting these individual messages before I can group them. I've seen that JMS implementations provide transaction batching over a set of messages as given in

[Document 1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e15493/batching.htm)

[Document 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0505_titheridge/0505_titheridge.html)

But I also want the acknowledgement of batch to be controlled by my code; as in case there is some issue in grouping, I should be able to rollback the batch I am reading, to be able to process the message in next try.

From above links, as the transaction is managed by container over a set of onMessage calls, I would not control the transaction commit and rollback.

Can someone let me know if I misreading it and what would be the way to achieve this?